# Keyboard events not registering after clicking on a combobox component

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox, keyboard

I'm creating a flash swf file where the user selects an option from a dropdown menu, and then pressing a key on the keyboard moves them to another frame in the timeline.

However, I've found that when clicking on the combobox, none of the keyboard buttons are being recognized. The keyboard code is simple enough. I only have formatting code for the combobox:

```
comboBox1.textField.setStyle("textFormat", tf1)
comboBox1.dropdown.setRendererStyle("textFormat", tf1)
comboBox1.setSize(85,25);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_Done);

function fl_Done(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{

    if (event.keyCode == 38 ){
    gotoAndPlay(10);
    }

}
```

Most of what I've found online either is over my head or doesn't work when I try it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 Flash change combobox value cause keydown events are disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540150/as3-flash-change-combobox-value-cause-keydown-events-are-disabled).

Comment: Yep, that answered my question. Thanks for the link!